# Subtraction between two numbers and displaying the result in a new pivot page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I want to create a subtraction function where the user inputs an earning and inputs an expenditure on separate pivots, then for it to display the result on a separate summary like pivot page.

Here is a screenshot of what I am roughly trying to accomplish:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This question is too general. I think you should start by reading some books/tutorials about MVVM and how to communicate between ViewModels.

Comment: where are you stuck? Please read the FAQ on what/when you can ask here. Also please tell us what you already got and maybe some code to clarify it.

Comment: MVVM I'll have a read up on this, thanks ken, just needed a nudge in the right direction :~)

Comment: @SynerCoder my sincere apologies

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Bill
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public double Value {get;set;}
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Bill> earnings;
    public ObservableCollection<Bill> Earnings
    {
        get {return earnings;}
        set
        {
            if (earnings != value)
            {
                earnings = value;

                if (earnings != null)
                {
                    earnings.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        NotifyPropertyChanged("Breakdown");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Outgoins the same as Earnings

    public double Breakdown
    {        
        get
        {
            Sum = 0;

            foreach (Bill in Earnings)
            {
                Sum += Bill.Value;
            }

            foreach (Bill in Outgoins)
            {
                Sum -= Bill.Value;
            }
            return Sum;
        }
    }
}
```